# Animated Splash in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, animated-gif, splash-screen

I am struggling with wxPython and animated (gif) splash during long taking function. So far I have:

```
class Splash(wx.SplashScreen):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=-1):

        image = "spinner.gif"
        aBitmap = wx.Image(name =image).ConvertToBitmap()
        splashStyle = wx.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_PARENT
        splashDuration = 0 # milliseconds
        wx.SplashScreen.__init__(self, aBitmap, splashStyle,
                                 splashDuration, parent)

        gif = wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl(self, id, image,)

        self.Show()
        self.gif = gif

    def Run(self,):
        self.gif.Play()
```

I would like to do something like:

```
splash = Splash()
splash.Run()
result = very_time_consuming_function()
splash.Close()
...
use the result
```

Any input will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should perform the time consuming work on another thread, otherwise GUI will block and not respond.

- Have a worker thread perform the time consuming task.
- Upon completing the task, inform the GUI thread so that the splash is destroyed.

Here is a snippet:

```
import wx
import wx.animate
from threading import Thread
import time

def wrap_very_time_consuming_function():
    print "sleeping"
    time.sleep(5) # very time consuming function
    print "waking up"
    wx.CallAfter(splash.gif.Stop)
    return 0

app = wx.App()
splash = Splash()
splash.Run()
Thread(target=wrap_very_time_consuming_function).start()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: But I need to use the return value from the function. Basically I would like to have the main function "wait" until the other function finish and use further on the return value and in a meanwhile having the splash spin. I tried also starting the splash in a separate thread and call the function from he main but it lets me run the animation only in the main thread.